# Node.js Client for Google Maps Services slow and discontinuous answer

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-maps, google-places-api

It's all the day **I'm trying to figure out where I did a mistake using Node.js Client for Google Maps Services** api's.

I need to get all the 60 results that the places function can return. This implies I must use `next_page_token` that the previous request returned to me.

```
const googleMapsClient = require( '@google/maps' ).createClient( {
    key : KEY
    , Promise : Promise
} );

let arr = [];
let tok = '';

Locations.prototype.foo = function ( context, args, callback ) {
let next_page = token => {
    googleMapsClient.places( { pagetoken : tok } )
        .asPromise()
        .then( newResponse => {

            // if the request is invalid, retry after 200ms
            if ( newResponse.json.status === 'INVALID_REQUEST' ) {
                log.info("retrying", TAG);
                return setTimeout( next_page, 2000, token );
            }

            // adding element retrivied
            log.info("picking", TAG);
            Array.prototype.push.apply( arr, newResponse.json.results );

            // if there are no page anymore, return to the callback
            if ( newResponse.json.next_page_token == undefined ) {
                log.info("callbacking", TAG);
                return callback(null, arr);
            }

            log.info("requesting again", TAG);
            // if there are more pages, request again
            tok = newResponse.json.next_page_token;
            return next_page( tok );
        });
};

googleMapsClient.places( {
    query : 'restaurant',
    language : 'en',
    location : [ -33.86746, 151.207090 ],
    radius : 5000
} )
    .asPromise()
    .then( response => {
        Array.prototype.push.apply( arr, response.json.results );
        tok = response.json.next_page_token;
    } )
    .then( () => {
        next_page( tok );
    });
```

}

I tried to look at the [tests the library proposes](https://github.com/googlemaps/google-maps-services-js/blob/master/spec/e2e/places-spec.js#L136), but unfortunately I'm not able to obtain the same result.

My problem is that when I perform the `GET` request, most of the time the promise time out. Sometimes instead the result is returned very quickly or after 30-45 seconds.

What I'm missing here?

Comment: Any Improvement because I m facing the same problem